# Dynamically change value in uib-tabset attribute

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

In my project I use `ui.bootstrap.tabs`. On `md` and `lg` screens tabs should appear vertically stacked, but on screens `sm` and `xs` I want to see them appear horizontally. All I need is to set value in vertical attribute either true or false. When screen size is changed, I have match on `md` or `lg` sizes and set property `vertical_tab_appearance = true` and the same with `sm` and `lg` sizes, property has `false` value, but `uib-tabset` directive does not know that the value of that property has changed.

```
 <div class="col-md-2 small hidden-print">
        <div ng-model="value">
            <uib-tabset vertical="vertical_tab_appearance" type="pills"> 
                <uib-tab></uib-tab>
            </uib-tabset> 
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is my screen size events:

```
 screenSize.on('md, lg', function (match) {
   if (match) {
       $scope.vertical_tab_appearance = true;
   }
  });

 screenSize.on('sm, xs', function (match) {
   if (match) {
       $scope.vertical_tab_appearance = false;
    }
  });
```

Can I do something here or I should use `ng-if` in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else will face the same problem, here is a solution. I decided to use `uibTabsetDirective` decorator in module config and add watcher to a vertical attribute in a linking function.

```
.config(function ($provide) {
            $provide.decorator('uibTabsetDirective', function($delegate) {
                var directive, link, scope;
                directive = $delegate[0];
                link = directive.link;
                scope = directive.scope;
                scope['vertical'] = '=';
                directive.compile = function() {
                  return function Link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                    scope.$watch(attrs.vertical, function() {
                        console.log(scope.vertical);
                    });

                    return link.apply(this, arguments);
                  };
                };
                return $delegate;
            });
        });
```